# how to clean output from symbols: plus minus pipe ( | - + )

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

using the sentence:

```
scala> val intento2 = sql("SELECT  _CreationDate  FROM tablaTemporal" )
intento2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_CreationDate: string]

scala>  intento2.show(5, false)
```

I receive this output:

```
+-----------------------+
|_CreationDate          |
+-----------------------+
|2008-07-31T00:00:00.000|
|2008-07-31T14:22:31.287|
|2008-07-31T14:22:31.287|
|2008-07-31T14:22:31.287|
|2008-07-31T14:22:31.317|
+-----------------------+ 
only showing top 5 rows
```

but the result I need is the same but no symbols added by scala/spark:

```
2005-07-31T14:20:19.239
2007-07-31T14:20:31.287
2009-07-31T14:21:33.287
2005-07-31T14:23:36.287
2009-07-31T14:20:38.317
```

How can i do, to print a clean output like above?

Answer (score 1):

Here, you're printing the dataframe.

What you want to do is print each record of the dataframe:

```
intento2.collect().map(_.getString(0)).foreach(println)
```

- collect transforms the dataframe into an array of Row objects.
- then we map each Row to its first element with row.getString(0). In fact the Row contains only one element, the date.